How to Restrict User Access to Their Own Directories in alexusmai/Laravel-File-Manager?
I'm developing a file management system in Laravel using the alexusmai/laravel-file-manager package. My goal is to create a system similar to Google Drive where users can manage their own files. For each user, I'm creating a unique directory during registration and storing the directory name in a base_directory_name field in the users' table. I want to ensure that users can only access the contents of their own directory.
In the package's configuration file, I've set the root path, and I’m using middleware to dynamically change the filesystem settings for each user. However, when the system runs, users are still able to access the entire root directory.
config/filesystems.php
'disks' => [
       'private' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/private'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'private',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

config/file-manager.php
/**
* List of disk names that we want to use
* (from config/filesystems)
*/

'diskList' => ['private'],

my middleware:
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if (Auth::guard("user")->check()) {
            $userDirectory = storage_path("app/private/"). Auth::guard("user")->user()->base_directory_name;
            
            Config::set('filesystems.disks.private.root', $userDirectory);
            //dd(Config::get('filesystems.disks.private.root'));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }

Notes:

If I manually change the config file, the access permissions work as expected, and users can only see their own files.
After applying the middleware, I used Config::get to check the settings, and I can confirm that the configuration changes dynamically at runtime as intended. However, the file access permissions still aren't applied correctly.

Could someone guide me on how to properly enforce dynamic directory access for each user? Am I missing something in the configuration or middleware setup?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

did you check the dynamic config guide ?
